# How to write KTable in a Kafka topic? Like we use "to()" in KStreams how to do that for KTable?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, ktable

As there is no "to()" method for KTable so do we need to always convert it to KStream before sending any message to a topic? 
Or how can we store a KTable in our topic?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in order to materialize a `KTable` to a topic, you're required to convert it to a regular stream (instead of a changelog stream) via `table.toStream().to("myTopic")`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `KTable` had a to method some time ago.

In general, if you check older versions of `KTable`, like [1.0](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KTable.html), you'll see that the API was simplified significantly and more than a dozen methods were deprecated, many of them deleted as of today, including `to()`:
[image]